# How to upload file with binary body node js

Tags: node.js, node-modules

Not able to upload file.Is this right way for binary body upload

```
fs.readFile("Koala.jpg", function(err, data) {
  if (err) throw err;

 request( {
      url     : url,
      method  : POST,
      json    : true,
      body    : data, 
      encoding: null,
      headers : {
    "Content-Type": "application/octet-stream"
      }
});
});
```

tried changing header content type to `image/jpeg`
tried with removing encoding null.
works fine with postman.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/sjidd.jpg

Comment: It seems you forgot to ask an actual question or perhaps state your issue.

Comment: facing issue for file upload

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way that I've found to upload binary file or image is to use the `form-data` [module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/form-data#alternative-submission-methods) along with `fs` as it eases the pain in submitting a `multipart/form-data` encoded request. The general steps if you decide to use this method are:

1. Create a new `form` using `form-data`
2. Use the `form.append` method along with the `fs.createReadStream`
   method to construct a form containing a file stream or `Buffer`
3. Create your `POST` request
4. Use the `form.pipe` method to pipe your `POST` request